# c# Use enum as Event args

Tags: c#, events, enums, eventargs

How to use an enum as Event Args to make an event? This code doesn't works

```
public static event EventHandler<Status> MyHandler

public enum Status : EventArgs
{
    ON,
    WAIT,
    OFF
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have an enum derive from anything.  You will need to put it in a class.

```
public class StatusArgs : EventArgs
{
    public enum StatusEnum
    {
        ON,
        WAIT,
        OFF
    }
    public StatusEnum Status { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has syntax errors, as well.

Switch it to

```
public static event EventHandler<Status> MyHandler;

public enum Status
{
    ON,
    WAIT,
    OFF
}
```